# How do I uninstall and reinstall Vmware tools on Manjaro?

Tags: linux, manjaro

Today I installed Manjaro on vmware and drag and drop doesn't work so
I want to remove vmwaretools or open vm tools and reinstall it
How do I do that on Manjaro?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I have uninstalled vmrc

List possible switches:

```
./VMware-Remote-Console-10.0.3-9300449.x86_64.bundle --help
```

To list installed components:

```
sudo ./VMware-Remote-Console-10.0.3-9300449.x86_64.bundle -l
```

To unistall vmrc

```
sudo ./VMware-Remote-Console-10.0.3-9300449.x86_64.bundle --uninstall-component=vmware-vmrc
```